# Accessing Spring beans from a Tiles view (JSP)

Tags: java, spring, jsp, spring-mvc, tiles

In Spring MVC I can access my beans in JSP using JstlView's exposedContextBeanNames (or exposeContextBeansAsAttributes). For example, then, in my JSP I can write (${properties.myProperty). But when the same JSP is a part of a tiles view, these properties aren't accessible. Is possible to configure Tiles properly or access these properties in another way?

I'm using Spring MVC 3.0.2 and Tiles 2.2.1. Here's a bit of my configuration:

```
<bean id="tilesViewResolver" class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.UrlBasedViewResolver">
    <property name="order" value="1"/>
    <property name="viewClass" value="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.tiles2.TilesView" />
</bean> 

<bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
    <property name="viewClass" value="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.JstlView"/>
    <property name="order" value="2"/>
    <property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/views/"/>
    <property name="suffix" value=".jsp"/>
    <property name="exposedContextBeanNames">
        <list><value>properties</value></list>
    </property>
</bean>
```

**EDIT:** I've implemented Skaffman's solution.

TilesExposingBeansViewResolver.java:

```
package es.kcsolutions.util.spring.servlet.view;

import org.springframework.web.servlet.view.*;

public class TilesExposingBeansViewResolver extends UrlBasedViewResolver {

    private Boolean exposeContextBeansAsAttributes;
    private String[] exposedContextBeanNames;

    public void setExposeContextBeansAsAttributes(boolean exposeContextBeansAsAttributes) {
        this.exposeContextBeansAsAttributes = exposeContextBeansAsAttributes;
    }

    public void setExposedContextBeanNames(String[] exposedContextBeanNames) {
        this.exposedContextBeanNames = exposedContextBeanNames;
    }

    @Override
    protected AbstractUrlBasedView buildView(String viewName) throws Exception {
        AbstractUrlBasedView superView = super.buildView(viewName);
        if (superView instanceof TilesExposingBeansView) {
            TilesExposingBeansView view = (TilesExposingBeansView) superView;
            if (this.exposeContextBeansAsAttributes != null) view.setExposeContextBeansAsAttributes(this.exposeContextBeansAsAttributes);
            if (this.exposedContextBeanNames != null) view.setExposedContextBeanNames(this.exposedContextBeanNames);
        }
        return superView;
    }

}
```

TilesExposingBeansView.java:

```
package es.kcsolutions.util.spring.servlet.view;

import java.util.*;
import javax.servlet.http.*;
import org.springframework.web.context.support.ContextExposingHttpServletRequest;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.view.tiles2.TilesView;

public class TilesExposingBeansView extends TilesView {

    private boolean exposeContextBeansAsAttributes = false;
    private Set<String> exposedContextBeanNames;

    public void setExposeContextBeansAsAttributes(boolean exposeContextBeansAsAttributes) {
        this.exposeContextBeansAsAttributes = exposeContextBeansAsAttributes;
    }

    public void setExposedContextBeanNames(String[] exposedContextBeanNames) {
        this.exposedContextBeanNames = new HashSet<String>(Arrays.asList(exposedContextBeanNames));
    } 

    protected HttpServletRequest getRequestToExpose(HttpServletRequest originalRequest) {
        if (this.exposeContextBeansAsAttributes || this.exposedContextBeanNames != null) 
        return new ContextExposingHttpServletRequest(originalRequest, getWebApplicationContext(), this.exposedContextBeanNames);
        return originalRequest;
    }

    @Override
    protected void renderMergedOutputModel(Map<String, Object> model, HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws Exception {
        HttpServletRequest requestToExpose = getRequestToExpose(request);
        exposeModelAsRequestAttributes(model, requestToExpose);
        super.renderMergedOutputModel(model, requestToExpose, response);
    }

}
```

Spring configuration:

```
    <bean id="tilesViewResolver" class="es.kcsolutions.util.spring.servlet.view.TilesExposingBeansViewResolver">
        <property name="order" value="1"/>
        <property name="viewClass" value="es.kcsolutions.util.spring.servlet.view.TilesExposingBeansView"/>
        <property name="exposedContextBeanNames">
            <list><value>properties</value></list>
        </property>
    </bean>
```

If you have some problem, take a look at TilesExposingBeansView.renderMergedOutputModel. I've made some tests, but maybe it's necessary to make a lot more.

Comment: did you google for spring tiles integration?

Comment: Yes, I googled. I have some troubles with previous versions, but now it was all ok, except for this issue. I searched for it but I've found nothing :(

Comment: man, spring and apache must write you a check for this ;) great job

Answer (score 12, accepted):

As you've noticed, this functionality is part of `InternalResourceViewResolver` and `InternalResourceView`, whereas the Tiles stuff inherits directly from `UrlBasedViewResolver` and `AbstractUrlBasedView`, so you can't make use of it.

Looking at the code, there's no reason why this stuff couldn't have been put into `AbstractUrlBasedView`. The magic happens in `InternalResourceView.getRequestToExpose`, and it looks perfectly applicable to `AbstractUrlBasedView` too.

In the short term, I suggest subclassing `UrlBasedViewResolver` and `TilesView`, copying the `getRequestToExpose` stuff from `InternalResourceView`. In the longer term, I encourage you to file a issue with [SpringSource](http://jira.springsource.org/) asking them to move this functionality up the class hierarchy into `AbstractUrlBasedView`, making it more widely available.

Comment: I've tried something similar, but it doesn't work. I've subclassed JstlView, overriding initServletContext, checkResource and renderMergedOutputModel. 

I'll try your idea now.

Comment: @Sinuhe: `JstlView` isn't going to be compatible with Tiles, the mechanisms are fundamentally different.

Comment: Well, your solution worked! While I was doing it, I've noticed my previous idea wasn't correct. I've try it a little more before filing an issue to SpringSource. Thanks!

Comment: @skaffman What are you views on 'ServletContextAttributeExporter'? Shouldn't we be using 'ServletContextAttributeExporter' instead of extending UrlBasedViewResolver's functionality?

Answer (score 13):

Have you tried to use *ServletContextAttributeExporter* in xml configuration file?

```
<bean
    class="org.springframework.web.context.support.ServletContextAttributeExporter">
    <property name="attributes">
        <map>
            <entry key="<bean key here>">
                <ref bean="<bean name here" />
            </entry>
        </map>
    </property>
</bean>
```

Comment: I use this because it is simpler to implement.

Comment: Certainly This is more elegant and unobtrusive method of adding session beans  ! I was about to extend the Spring Classes, your solution saved my several days of work ! THANK YOU !

Answer (score 1):

As of Spring 3.0 there is now a [TilesViewResolver](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/servlet/view/tiles2/TilesViewResolver.html).

> Convenience subclass of UrlBasedViewResolver that supports TilesView
>   (i.e. Tiles definitions) and custom subclasses of it.
>
> The view class for all views generated by this resolver can be
>   specified via the "viewClass" property. See UrlBasedViewResolver's
>   javadoc for details.
>
> Note: When chaining ViewResolvers, a TilesViewResolver will check for
>   the existence of the specified template resources and only return a
>   non-null View object if the template was actually found.
>
> Since:
>   3.0 Author: Juergen Hoeller

Comment: TilesViewResolver doesnt solve the problem as it subclasses UrlBasedViewResolver without adding exposedContextBeanNames property. The original post and the accepted answer are still the best way to go AFAIK.