# Accessing Spring 3 beans in tiles 3 expressions in definition file

Tags: spring, tiles

I am using *Spring 3.2* and *tiles 3.0*.

I want to set the value of an attribute in a tiles definition from a spring bean property like this

```
<put-attribute name="headTitle" expression="${msgs['serviceGroups.title']}" />
```

msgs is *HashMap* and it is defined in spring application context

```
<bean id="msgs" class="qa.gov.moi.eservices.web.util.MessageSourceMapAdapter">
    <constructor-arg name="messageSource">
        <ref bean="messageSource"/>
    </constructor-arg>
</bean>
```

and this is spring-tiles config

```
<bean id="tilesConfigurer" class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.tiles3.TilesConfigurer">
    <property name="definitions">
        <list>
            <value>/WEB-INF/tiles-defs.xml</value>
        </list>
    </property>
</bean>
```

and this the template default.jsp

```
<html>
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
    <title><tiles:getAsString name="headTitle"/></title>


</head>
<body>
    <div id="wrapper">
        <div id="container">
            <div id="top_header">
                <tiles:insertAttribute name="heading" />
                <tiles:insertAttribute name="menuTab" />
                <tiles:insertAttribute name="genralizationTab" />
            </div><!-- top_header -->
            <tiles:insertAttribute name="content" />
            <tiles:insertAttribute name="footer" />
        </div><!-- container -->
    </div><!-- wrapper -->
</body>
```

when i tried to run the application i got the following exception

```
 Uncaught exception created in one of the service methods of the servlet /WEB-INF/jsp/layouts/default.jsp in application eservices. Exception created : java.lang.NullPointerException
```

except this issue every thing is OK.

Is there any way to make spring beans accessible to tiles expressions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is divided to couple of small problems:

1 - The first one is to enable `tiles` to access `spring` beans and this can be done by   exposing spring context beans to Tiles view - [check this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2848415/accessing-spring-beans-from-a-tiles-view-jsp?rq=1) provided by mck.

2 - The second one is how to render the attribute in the `JSP`, using `tiles:getAsString` tag with an `put-attribute` have no value will throw `NullPointerException` as the `tiles:getAsString` tag uses the simple `toString()` on the value provided in the definition to render itself and it completely will ignore the `expression` attribute, instead of `getAsString` use `insertAttribute`which can evaluate the `expression`.

```
<!--this works fine with expressions-->
<tiles:insertAttribute name="headTitle" ignore="true" />

<!-- and this will throw NullPointerException if value is not provided-->
<tiles:getAsString name="headTitle" ignore="true"/>
```