# Spring Properties File in a JSP 3.2.8

Tags: jsp, spring-mvc, jstl, properties-file

Having the file \WEB-INF\application.properties, with the properties:

```
templateName = templateName
```

I just defined the bean

```
<bean id="applicationProperties" class="org.springframework.beans.factory.config.PropertiesFactoryBean">
            <property name="locations">
                <list><value>classpath:application.properties</value></list>
            </property> 
</bean>
```

expose it to the ViewResolver:

```
<!-- Resolves view name to template & body -->
    <bean name="templateViewResolver" class="springext.web.servlet.mvc.support.TemplateViewResolver">
        <property name="viewClass" value="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.JstlView" />
        <property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/jsp/" />
        <property name="templateMap">
            <bean class="springext.web.servlet.mvc.support.TemplateMapFactory">
                <property name="templateDir" value="/WEB-INF/jsp/template/" />
                <property name="templateSuffix" value="Template.jsp" />
                <property name="bodySuffix" value="Body.jsp" />
            </bean>
        </property>
        <property name="exposedContextBeanNames">
            <list><value>applicationProperties</value></list>
        </property>
    </bean>
```

the property does not show up in a jsp using

```
${applicationProperties.templateName}
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that if you place your application.properties inside `\WEB-INF\application.properties` it won't be available on classpath, which will scan from `/WEB-INF/classes`. Place it inside `/src/main/resources` and it should work for you

Comment: I put it there with the same result :-(

Comment: make sure to do a clean build of a war (if your using maven mvn clean package), and than check where inside the war is the file placed, should be inside /WEB-INF/classes

Comment: I did it with the same result. Strange :-(

Comment: and the properties file is inside WEB-INF/classess ?

Comment: yes, inside WEB-INF/classes and inside resources/config/application.properties. I opened the war and verified that it is inside

Comment: configuration wise you are fine, the only other thing that comes to my mind is related to the actual implementation of the TemplateViewResolver, you can check this question to see if it holds for your case as well http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2848415/accessing-spring-beans-from-a-tiles-view-jsp